# Add two split string values in c#

Tags: c#

I need to add split string values to get the rounded value.

```
string Temp1="0.0154275894165039,1.11531066894531,0.294834136962891,";

string[] Temp2=Temp1.Split(',');
```

How to sum the values coming in "temp2" and assign it to another parameter.

Comment: In addition to the answers posted below, you'll probably want some code to handle the case when the split strings cannot be parsed as doubles, to handle any abnormal input you might receive in production; `if (!double.TryParse(s, out num)) HandleInvalidInput();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
values.Select(double.Parse).Sum()
```

Comment: Of course this will fail if your input is malformed and doesn't just contain numbers

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
double dSum = 0;

foreach (string sStr in Temp2)
    dSum += Double.parse(sStr);
```

Comment: As with the LINQ solution, you should really cater for the possibility that some of your input won't be numbers

Answer (score 1):

Consider also passing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to `double.Parse`. Otherwise your solution will fail on systems running on certain localization settings.